# Show password protected page password in admin page Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, password-protection

I have a page in the admin area of Wordpress that I intend to use for the admin to be able to change the password of (any) password protected page.

**Right now I've tried 1)**

```
<?php
function the_post_password()
    {
        $post = get_post();
        if ( isset( $post->post_password ) )
            echo esc_attr( $post->post_password );
    }
?>
```

**2) and this**

```
<?php
$the_post = get_post( 3772 );
echo ("$the_post->post_password");
?>
```

**What I get is:**

> **Fatal error:** Cannot redeclare the_post_password() (previously declared in /home/mysite/public_html/mysite/wp-admin/includes/template.php:1521) [**this is where I got that declaration from]

1 -  Gives me the error because its already declared?!?

2 - Just does nothing

All I'm trying to do is show the password for the page from the `wp-db` `post_password` (its not encrypted). The admin can see the password of the page onscreen like: The page (page name) password is: xxxxxx

I don't want this for the `users_logged_in` - this is to be seen only by the admin the admin can change the password from the interface (the page I've made - or link to it from the same page.

How do I go about getting the password from the db to display on the page? and... if possible the page name - post ID

Comment: Please use echo $the_post->post_password; instead of echo ("$the_post->post_password");... the way you have given is wrong

Comment: Not a very secure way to store plaintext passwords.

Comment: Used the answer from Rahul S. and it worked!... 

I have a form on the protected page requesting password access (prior to the protected password field) *this only shows when not password accessed

I added the string into an auto email to the person ( when they request a pwd access ) and it auto fills it from the [$the_post->post_password] - that also works, yay.

Now I need a way to be able to change the pwd using an input field to the postID and the post_password